# Dependency for functions in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

How can I create dependency for functions in swift to run one after another? In other words, I want one function to wait until another one completes its task successfully.

```
var sales : NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()
var items : NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()


override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
```

This is where I need help, the below dispatch method is not working properly, I get the “index 0 beyond bounds for empty array” error since the array is not populated yet I guess. Also I am not sure that if this is the right method to handle this…

```
/*
        dispatch_async(queue, {

            dispatch_sync(queue, {
                self.downloadItems()
            })

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.displayItems()
            })
        })
*/

}

func downloadItems() {

let urlPath = "……………………………"
let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)

let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

   if (error != nil) {
        println(error)
    } else {

    let jsonResult: AnyObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)!

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

        for var i = 0; i < jsonResult.count; i++ {
            self.sales[i] = jsonResult[i]["daily_sales"] as NSString

        }
    }
    }
    })

task.resume()

}


func displayItems() {

self.items.addObject(["amount": self.sales[0]])

}
```

Comment: You need to try writing the code, post that with a description of the problems, SO is about helping write code, not providing code.

Comment: Look at dispatch queues with groups - you can wait on their completion.

Comment: Synchronous functions? Asynchronous functions?

Comment: One function calling the other?

Answer (score 0):

Use 'continuation passing style'.  Your operation `downloadItems()` will take an argument with a function to perform once `downloadItems()` completes - the argument is similar to a `continuation` (which some languages expose, see Scheme and ML for details).  So it looks like:

```
func downloadItems (continuation: (Void -> Void)!) {
  let urlPath = // ...
  // ...

  if nil != continuation { continuation() }
}
```

and then you'd use it with

```
self.downloadItems { [self unowned] in self.displayItems() }
```

Comment: Thanks , but I still get the same error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'